# My first Delphi Xe5 IOS App (using Mac in the Cloud)

Tags: macos, delphi, delphi-xe5

I was attempting to follow this tutorial in order to test Delphi Xe5 IOS app development using Mac in the Cloud

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zORe2voUHIU

I received the following info in email

Your server name  is: L108

Your Mac username is: userXXXX

Your Mac  password is: pasXXXXX

I also received a remote desktop connection link on my desktop :)

When clicked, the remote Mac machine is launched (says I am connecting to LA204) and my PA server (PA3609) terminal window is available.

No sure why the email says my server is L108 and the remote connection link is connecting me to LA204   (I need a New York Server)

Using the following commands:

? for help

p = port  and i = ip address

port = 64270
ip address = 74.80.228.166

Using Delphi Xe5 "connections profile manager"I created my profile Platform OS X, Host: 74.80.228.166, port # 64211 (also tried 64270)

However, Test connection failed

Any help would be greatly appreciated - I am burning up all my test time trying to do this on my own.

Comment: A terminal window is available, but are you running the PAServer in that window? Did you set a password for PAServer connections?

Comment: Marcus, the terminal window looks like it is called PA Server. I probably should not be using the term "terminal window", but that is what was mentioned din the video (link i provided).  Becuase this is a test trial (30 days, or 24 hours, which ever comes first), Mac In the Cloud provided me with a user name and password as I stated above.

Comment: Good Gawd!  After more than 24 hours after submitting a ticket to Mac in the Cloud, this is their response: "Thank you for contacting us at MacinCloud Support. We will take a further look in to your account. Let us know if you have any more questions in the meantime. We appreciate your patience. Thank you!"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future information for those you seek it, this is what the support team claims has happened (although I dispute the claim :) )

> "Sir,
>
> From your previous description, you appear to have received two
>   accounts:
>
> #1: an account on server LA204 (please review which particular email has this information sent to you)
>
> #2: an account on server L108 and username userXXXX (if you review the email that was sent to you with this login information, there is a
>   download link right below the login information that you should use
>   with this particular account)
>
> From your description, you mentioned that "I also received a remote
>   desktop connection link on my desktop" This only happens through
>   Embacadero's integrated signup process, which creates a connection
>   file on your desktop.
>
> If you sign up through our own website, and if you download through
>   the download link provided in the email, the connection file will be a
>   zip file in your download folder, no connection file will be
>   automatically created on your desktop.
>
> Here we attach a screenshot of the email we issued to you, as you may
>   see in this email, the download link that was provided is "Please
>   download your MacinCloud  connection files from the following link:
>   http://www.macincloud.com/images/MacinCloud_Lion_L108.zip"
>
> The connection profile that is pointing to LA204 can only come from a
>   different source. Our best guess is that you have also signed up
>   through Embarcadero's integrated trial process. It is not uncommon
>   that this happens and this could be the cause of the confusion."

NOTE: I never signed up from Embarcadero's site or IDE, I only signed up from Mac In the Cloud website. In any case, this is what they claimed happened and as far as I am concerned, as long ad it is working, I am happy.